# Can I still go to heaven if I had unintentional gay sex before puberty?

Tags: sex, children, homosexuality

My cousin and I were alone one night and we were bored. He tempted me to have intercourse with him. I'm a boy and so is he. It was such a situation for me that I couldn't reject, but now I am very guilty about my deed.

So I had a gay intercourse with him. But we never had anal , we just rubbed our “things together”.

I have done it about 6 time and masturbated 4 times with more people. I also kinda did a blow job where he put it in his month for 2 sec and one time he put his tip in my behind! It was 5 or 6 different people.

This was before puberty. I’m special ed/ I have ADHD (I didn’t know better) All of them were older then me like a year older. To this day I still regret it.

I was young and dumb and afraid I’m gonna go to hell. Will God forgive me?

Comment: I’m 16 about to be 17 and all this was around the age of 12 or under

Comment: I would advise you, when you ask this kind of questions. You don't need tell us every details if it's not 'necessary'. Like "I did some messed up gay stuff in past will I be forgiven?" Like that. It's better to hide your sin from people. And regret, ask forgiveness from Allah. He is ever merciful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were really young and you were not entirely responsible for your acts. If you don't think the same way, well, the door of repentance is always open to you.

It is known that homosexuality is banned by the Quran. But we also know that Islam says that every person is worth the same regardless of their origin, sexual orientation or skin colour. Gay intercourse doesn't mean that you are gay so I don't know whether you are gay or not. But I would like you to know that it is okay to be gay. Islam is about being a good person and having contribution to the world. My opinion might be a bit unpopular one. But this is a matter of belief.

Answer (score -1):

The most brutal punishment was given to people in Prophet Lut era because of their habit of homosexuality as per Quran.
We all should keep seeking forgiveness and mercy of Allah for our sins and promise will not do it again. This is what all we can do. Allah knows our intentions very well as our past is not in our hands but we can avoid the sins in future.